# python rembg - change background color

Tags: python, background, opencv, rembg

I remove background but instead of having a transparent background I would like to have green for example but I don't understand how to do it.

I want to change the background of my image for that I do:

```
from rembg import remove
import cv2
image = cv2.imread(imgPath)
removeim = remove(im)
```

But no idea for complete background with a color...

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

use this

"removeim = **remove(im,bgcolor=[255,0,0,255])**"

this will give you an output with complete red background.

change *bgcolor=[255,0,0,255]* to **bgcolor=[0,255,0,255]** to get **complete green background.**